# В консоль все нормально выводит, а в файл не пишет

Tags: python

Есть код, который при изменении файла выводит в консоль оповещение о том, что файл был изменен. Одновременно с этим он должен дополнительно записывать то же оповещение в файл, но почему-то в консоль все нормально выводит, а в файл не пишет. Не могу понять в чём проблема, помогите.

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    buffer = file.read()

log_file = open('log.txt', 'w')

while True:
    content = open('test.txt').read()
    if buffer != content:
        print('Change!')
        log_file.write('Change')
    buffer = content
```

Comment: Добавьте `log_file.flush()` после `log_file.write`...

Comment: @MaxU Сработало, можете объяснить этот момент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
log_file.write('Change')
```

пишет в файл средствами OS. Операционная система решает сама когда сбросить буфер на диск, поэтому скорее всего сразу в файле на диске ничего не появится.

```
log_file.flush()
```

дает комманду OS "сбросить" файловый буфер на диск.

При открытии файла мы можем управлять буферизацией при помощи параметра `open(..., buffering=...)`:

> The optional **buffering** argument specifies the file’s desired buffer
>   size: 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line buffered, any other positive
>   value means use a buffer of (approximately) that size (in bytes). A
>   negative buffering means to use the system default, which is usually
>   line buffered for tty devices and fully buffered for other files. If
>   omitted, the system default is used.

из доки Python 3.6:

> buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy.
>   Pass 0 to switch buffering off (only allowed in binary mode), 1 to
>   select line buffering (only usable in text mode), and an integer > 1
>   to indicate the size in bytes of a fixed-size chunk buffer. When no
>   buffering argument is given, the default buffering policy works as
>   follows:
>
> Binary files are buffered in fixed-size chunks; the size of the buffer
>   is chosen using a heuristic trying to determine the underlying
>   device’s “block size” and falling back on io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE. On
>   many systems, the buffer will typically be 4096 or 8192 bytes long.
>   “Interactive” text files (files for which isatty() returns True) use
>   line buffering. Other text files use the policy described above for
>   binary files.

Comment: Стоит упомянуть явно, что файлы по умолчанию полностью буферезированы, а при выводе прямо в консоль, буфер очищается после каждой строчки. (Посмотрите [вторую причину из pexpect FAQ](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)) о происхождении такого поведения